# Get Current Column Index from columnCount activereports

Tags: c#, activereports

I have a section reports with columnCount value as 6. I want to take the current column Index when the data are filling in down accross direction in the script.
[image: Column Index as following image]

Is there a way to achieve this. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of code for the down-across direction:

```
Dim locationY As Integer = 100 
Private Sub Detail_BeforePrint(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Detail.BeforePrint
    If Detail.CurrentLocation.Y < locationY Then
        TextBox1.Text = "new column"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "continue"
    End If
    locationY = Detail.CurrentLocation.Y
End Sub
```

Changing Y to X could help with across-down case.